# Calculate area of holes in image opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to calculate area of holes in an image.I have calculated number of holes in an image .

```
findContours( rois[wp], contourss, hierarchyy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
if ( !contourss.empty() && !hierarchyy.empty() ) {
   for ( int i=0; i<contourss.size(); i++ ) {
      if ( hierarchyy[i][3] != -1 ) {
         holes++;
      }
   }
}
```

Now i need to calculate area of these holes.Can someone help me in calculating area of holes

Comment: findContours( rois[wp], contourss, hierarchyy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
     if ( !contourss.empty() && !hierarchyy.empty() ) {
      for ( int i=0; i<contourss.size(); i++ ) {
          if ( hierarchyy[i][3] != -1 ) {
    holes++;
          }
      }
 }                                       My code fo calculating number of holes in an image

Comment: Don't post code or other important or relevant information as comments. *Edit your question* instead.

Comment: `if(...) { holes++; double holeArea = contourArea(contourss[i]); }`

Comment: Thanks.It works.